# Twig variable in string

Tags: twig

First of all I don't have the abillity to create custom functions of somekind. My question need to be done with the frontend options of Twig. And yes I'm pretty new to Twig :)

I'm trying to add some Twig variables to a javascript variable. That javascript variable is used to translate text to different languages.

The end result need to be:

```
var ajaxTranslations = {{ 'Free shipping; In stock; Natural; Juice;' | t_json | raw }}; 
// so Natural and Juice need to added in the exact same way as above
```

So I have a Twig variable that have some text in it like so:

```
{{ product_usp }} // results in -> Natural, Juice
```

So first I want to split that string (after each comma) into two seperate values. 
Next I want to create an array with those values and add them to that javascript variable. That's where my problems start.

How do you add `tusp` to that javascript variable?

What I did is this:

```
 {% set tusp = [] %}
  {% set usps = theme.product_usp | split(',') %}

  {% for usp in usps %}
   {% set tusp = usp ~ ';' %}
  {% endfor %}

<script>
    var ajaxTranslations = {{ 'Free shipping; In stock; ~ tusp' | t_json | raw }};
<script>
```

This results in empty value or `~ tusp` is seen as text instead of a value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `t_json`? is that a custom filter?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Could be but the `tusp` variable is not concatenated or interpolated correctly.

Comment: If you found this answer useful please vote for the answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the tilde operator it must be located in between a string(s) and/or a variable(s):

```
<script>
    var ajaxTranslations = "{{ 'Free shipping; In stock; ' ~ tusp | raw }}";
<script>
```

Or you can use "string interpolation":

```
<script>
    var ajaxTranslations = "{{ "Free shipping; In stock; #{tusp}" | raw }}";
<script>
```

Comment: Do note you will need to wrap the statement in parantheses or the filter `t_json` will only be applied to the variable `tusp`

Comment: @Michael Nino; Those both options is something I've tried. Both give a result like this: `{&quot;&quot`  or `#(tusp}`. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: If you would like to assign a string to a JavaScript variable you might do the following: `var ajaxTranslations = "{{ 'Free shipping; In stock; ' ~ tusp | raw }}";` instead. I don't believe you need to use a filter e.g., t_json. I am assuming this filter is a custom filter you are someone has defined for you.

Comment: Here is the Twig Documentation for encoding to JSON: See [json_encode](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html). You don't need to json_encode since you are assigning a string value to a JavaScript variable. However, you should read the documentation if you are interested in assigning arrays to a JavaScript variable.